# How to fill a vector with the results of a for loop in julia?

Tags: julia

I'm building a kalman filter to extimate arma models, now I've made it for an arma(1,1). In order to optimize the likelihood function I need to store all the values of the innovations and of them covariance matrix. 
I'm new to julia and I've used mostly r. 
 That's my code:

```
    for i=1:length(y)
x=A*x
Vt=y[i]-Z'x
Ft=Z'*P*Z
Kt=(A*P*Z)/Ft
x=A*x+Kt*Vt
P=A*(P-(P*Z*Z'*P)/Ft)*A'+R*R'*sigma^2
end
```

And it's working. If i try to store the Vt values in this way:

```
v= zeros(1:1000)
for i=1:length(y)
x=A*x
Vt=y[i]-Z'x
v[i]=Vt
Ft=Z'*P*Z
Kt=(A*P*Z)/Ft
x=A*x+Kt*Vt
P=A*(P-(P*Z*Z'*P)/Ft)*A'+R*R'*sigma^2
end
```

I get an error message thta says: *"MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Array{Float64,1} to an object of type Int64"*
I've tried to do it in different ways, like using dataframs etc, but i keep reciving errors about the type of objects not being convertible, I only managed to save the last value of Vt as a dataframe, but i need its values during all the loop. 
How could i solve this problem? I think that it's someting really simple but i'm not used to program. Thank you!

Comment: The problem is that Vt is a Vector of values, not a single value, so you can't put it into an element of v. If you know that Vt is always a Vector of length 1, you can just replace `v[i]=Vt` with `v[i]=Vt[1]`

Comment: Thank you! It seems to work fine if i do it "manually", but it says "InexactError()" when i lounch the loop, I have no idea about the reasons...

Comment: Change the `zeros(1:1000)` to `zeros(1000)`. The latter creates a 1000 long zero Float64 vector. The former turns out to create an Int64 vector.

Comment: Thanks, now it's working properly! It was very helpfull!

Comment: Good catch - passing an `AbstractVector` `a` to `zeros` calls `zeros(typeof(a), length(a))`, often convenient but surprising sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reiterating answers from comments:

Change the `zeros(1:1000)` to `zeros(1000)`. And make sure RHS and LHS of assignment `v[i]=Vt` are of the same shape/type by replacing with `v[i]=Vt[1]` or making sure `Vt` is a scalar.

Passing an `AbstractVector a` (this time `a` was `1:1000`) to `zeros` calls `zeros(typeof(a), length(a))`, which is often convenient but surprising sometimes.